# javascript execute button click event

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript. Please find the below code for button,

```
<p class="actions">
   <button class="button primary" type="submit">Login</button> 
    <a href="FreeSpiritEnrollment.aspx">Sign Up</a>
</p>
```

I need code to click this button. Anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the rest of your code including the script section so we can see what you have there?

Basically however, if you just need the button to register a click I would change the button Id to an element since it's a unique element.  Let's call it id =button1 . Then in your script section you would type

```
  document.getElementById("button1").onclick=function(){
}
```

And type what you want to happen inside the {}

Comment: This is a code from website. I need to login to this page. Is it possible to login with the above code?

Comment: I believe this is part of a broader question.  You need to be more specific about posting the entire question and all applicable code.  Asking piecemeal will not get you the answer your looking for.